# PowerQuery/PowerBi - How to keep top rows until the first NULL value appears?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I need to filter out the rows that come after the first NULL value. The row containing the null value should be filtered out as well. Please not this is a dynamic table, hence I cannot use the "Delete bottom rows" utility.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

I've tried adding a custom column but I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Add a step:

```
= Table.FirstN(#"Changed Type", List.PositionOf( #"Changed Type"[Fecha], null))
```

**#"Changed Type"** is the name of your previous step.

[image]

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Fecha", type datetime}, {"Numero", Int64.Type}}),
    Custom1 = Table.FirstN(#"Changed Type", List.PositionOf( #"Changed Type"[Fecha], null))
in
    Custom1
```